# How do I delete mod_python?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-python

I keep getting these errors in my Apache logs:

```
[error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.6.5+', found '2.6.6'.
[error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.6/:/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload'.
[notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
```

From what I've read, these errors come from mod_python. I'm using Flask and WSGI for my Python project, however, so I don't know why these errors are coming up.

Is there an easy way I can delete mod_python? - I've tried a2dismod, but mod_python doesn't appear to exist, even though I see it within Apache's mods-available directory.

**EDIT:** I've just tried a2dismod python, and that seems to have worked. I think I n00bishly was trying to disable mod_python. My Python apps still appear to work just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Look through your `httpd.conf` file, and remove the line that says:

```
LoadModule mod_python   /path/to/mod_python.so
```

Then restart apache:

```
apachectl restart
```

Comment: My httpd.conf file was empty, I tried **a2dismod python** and that seemed to work, before I was trying **a2dismod mod_python**. I'm a bit new at this >.<.

Comment: If your httpd.conf file is empty, then there's probably a different conf file used to load various modules. I was unaware of the a2dismod tool.